# What causing this issue when capturing screen shot with PIXI JS

Tags: web, ember.js, pixi.js, openfin

I have used PIXI JS to capture screen and save as screenshots. It works fine on some screens and it gives and error on another screen. Anyone have an idea which causing this error?

[image]

Comment: How big is your canvas? This may be the issue: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/867

Comment: @domis86 Thank you will check on it (Y).